# Parallel execution in grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

While executing tests in parallel which are in different packages, we are getting an error.The two browsers will launch, but while executing one test will execute while other browsers will lose focus.

Kindly help to resolve

Comment: Way too broad, can you give us a bit more info?

Comment: Agreed.  On the surface, it sounds like a threading issue with the WebDriver, but more information would be needed to determine that for sure.  Please add your code where you configure and start your WebDriver and we can start from there.